# Excel VBA - Delete empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to delete the empty rows my ERP Quotation generates. I'm trying to go through the document (`A1:Z50`) and for each row where there is no data in the cells (`A1-B1...Z1 = empty`, `A5-B5...Z5 = empty`) I  want to delete them.

I found this, but can't seem to configure it for me.

```
On Error Resume Next
Worksheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: You have tried substituting `A:A` with `C:C`, have you?

Comment: Serg, it seems I was wrong explaining my problem. I need to check an entire row (A1-Z1) to see whether it's empty or not, and this down to A50-Z50.

Comment: So a "whole row" for your purposes is columns A-Z and not like AA...ZZ...?

Comment: Yes, column A1 to Z1 is an entire row for me. If there aren't any items in any of these cells (A1 to Z1) then the row is empty and can be deleted.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about

```
sub foo()
  dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z50")
  rows = r.rows.Count
  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wasn't too bad, just bit too long for my needs atm. Someone else who might have the same problem will be helped with your example though ;)

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To 50
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i & ":" & "Z" & i)) = 0 Then
            If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRange = Range("A" & i & ":" & "Z" & i)
            Else
                Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, Range("A" & i & ":" & "Z" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete shift:=xlUp
LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

IF you want to delete the entire row then use this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To 50
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i & ":" & "Z" & i)) = 0 Then
            If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRange = Rows(i)
            Else
                Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete shift:=xlUp
LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, not sure whether it works, but it's a bit longer than the snippet I accepted.

Comment: @Tom: It is longer because I have used the right way to code with all error handling. Anyways leave it ;)

Comment: Oh sorry :) I only needed a quick fix though. Thanks for the thorough example though :)

Answer (score 12):

I know I am late to the party, but here is some code I wrote/use to do the job.

```
Sub DeleteERows()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("a2:A15000").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Give this man a damn medal. Oldest and simplest solution to date.

Comment: Will delete the entire row if there is at least one empty cell?

Comment: Working nicely!
Just beware of combined cells (which I got automatically after copy/paste data out of a grid control with line breaks). For me, with the combined cells, too much got deleted.

Answer (score 2):

for those who are intersted to remove "empty" and "blank" rows ( Ctrl + Shift + End going deep down of your worksheet ) .. here is my code.
It will find the last "real"row in each sheet and delete the remaining blank rows.

```
Function XLBlank()
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Activate
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
        
        Range("A" & lRow + 1, Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).Select
        On Error Resume Next
        Selection.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        Cells(1, 1).Select
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
End Function
```

Open VBA ( ALT + F11 ), Insert -> Module,
Copy past my code and launch it with F5.
Et voila :D

Answer (score 2):

I have another one for the case when you want to delete only rows which are complete empty, but not single empty cells. It also works outside of Excel e.g. on accessing Excel by Access-VBA or VB6.

```
Public Sub DeleteEmptyRows(Sheet As Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim Row As Range
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim Count As Long

    If Sheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' We are iterating across a collection where we delete elements on the way.
    ' So its safe to iterate from the end to the beginning to avoid index confusion.
    For Index = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Row = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows(Index)

        ' This construct is necessary because SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        ' always throws runtime errors if it doesn't find any empty cell.
        Count = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        Count = Row.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Count = Row.Cells.Count Then Row.Delete xlUp
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: works, just I recommend to use `Sub DeleteEmptyRows(Sheet)` instead of `DeleteEmptyRows(Sheet As Excel.Worksheet)`. I used `DeleteEmptyRows (Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets("sheet1"))`

Comment: Good advise. In fact, I took this out of my Excel class, so `Sheet` is normally a class internal local variable and the Subs Header would be just `Sub DeleteEmptyRows()`. To adapt it for here, I added the parameter so that it works as standalone function. This one collides maybe with the fact, that we have in Excel Worksheet-Objects as well as Sheet-Objects which are not the same in every case despite they discribe the same entity. Feel free to change it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the quickest way to Delete all blank Rows ( based on one Columns )

```vb
Dim lstRow as integet, ws as worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfSheet")

With ws

     lstRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' Or Rows.Count "B", "C" or "A" depends 

     .Range("A1:E" & lstRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End with
```

Answer (score 0):

To make Alex K's answer slightly more dynamic you could use the code below:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngIdx As Long, _
    lngColCounter As Long
Dim blnAllBlank As Boolean
Dim UserInputSheet As String

UserInputSheet = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet which you wish to remove empty rows from")

Set wks = Worksheets(UserInputSheet)

With wks
    'Now that our sheet is defined, we'll find the last row and last column
    lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lngLastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'Since we need to delete rows, we start from the bottom and move up
    For lngIdx = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1

        'Start by setting a flag to immediately stop checking
        'if a cell is NOT blank and initializing the column counter
        blnAllBlank = True
        lngColCounter = 2

        'Check cells from left to right while the flag is True
        'and the we are within the farthest-right column
        While blnAllBlank And lngColCounter <= lngLastCol

            'If the cell is NOT blank, trip the flag and exit the loop
            If .Cells(lngIdx, lngColCounter) <> "" Then
                blnAllBlank = False
            Else
                lngColCounter = lngColCounter + 1
            End If

        Wend

        'Delete the row if the blnBlank variable is True
        If blnAllBlank Then
            .rows(lngIdx).delete
        End If

    Next lngIdx
End With


MsgBox "Blank rows have been deleted."

 End Sub
```

This was sourced from [this website](https://danwagner.co/deleting-blank-rows-in-a-variable-range-with-vba/) and then slightly adapted to allow the user to choose which worksheet they want to empty rows removed from.

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me (you can adjust lastrow and lastcol as needed):

```
Sub delete_rows_blank2()

t = 1
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Do Until t = lastrow

For j = 1 To lastcol
    'This only checks the first column because the "Else" statement below will skip to the next row if the first column has content.
    If Cells(t, j) = "" Then

        j = j + 1

            If j = lastcol Then
            Rows(t).Delete
            t = t + 1
            End If

    Else
    'Note that doing this row skip, may prevent user from checking other columns for blanks.
        t = t + 1

    End If

Next

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the On Error Resume function work you must declare the workbook and worksheet values as such

```
On Error Resume Next  
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet Name").Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete  
On Error GoTo 0
```

I had the same issue and this eliminated all the empty rows without the need to implement a For loop.