# Finding the number of cells in a row that has data

Tags: c#, excel

So I'm having a problem finding the number of rows in an excel document that has data in it. Here's what I have so far:

```
        for (int i = 2; i <= b; i++)
        {
            if (!(worksheet.get_Range("A" + i, misValue).Formula == null))
            {
                a.Add(worksheet.get_Range("A" + i, misValue).Formula);
            }
        }
```

At the moment I'm just crudely shuffling through a large number of lines, questioning whether it's null or not, then adding the contents to a list. There has to be an easier way that google has yet to show me. Thanks for the help in advanced

Comment: where did you assign `b`?

Comment: Just previously in code (this isn't the whole program)   (int b = worksheet.Rows.Count;)

Comment: what is misValue, are you checking all rows of many columns or all rows of one column?

Comment: Somewhere in the code (either yours or on a lower level) the worksheet has to be 'parsed' out.

Comment: One column, misValue is just "System.Reflection.Missing.Value".  The way it's setup works, but is painfully slow. It takes an average of a tenth of a second to process one cell (with test data) but once applied on a larger scale, speed could become an issue.

Comment: Two links that might help: 1) General Performance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356371/excel-interop-efficiency-and-performance) and 2) Empty Row - Deletion in this case, but you can use it to detect emptiness (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379673/excel-vba-delete-empty-rows)

Comment: @RichardMorgan Thanks that might work

Comment: I assume there is a specific need for using C# or VBA iinstead of CountA (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/counta-HP005209027.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding your question properly, but I'm guessing you're trying to find all the cells in column A that have a value in them and I'm assuming you're using `Excel Interop` in C#...

For that, you can use the `Range.SpecialCells` method.

So, for example, to get cells with constant values or formulas use:

```
worksheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants |
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas)
```

That will return a range you can loop through and add to your list, `a`....

See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Hope this helps...