# Aligning data in two columns in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA Excel. I wanted to write a code that aligns data in Column A to that in Column B then deletes the empty rows left
My Data example is as follows:

[image: Unsorted Data]

Desired output looks like this.

[image: Sorted Data]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379673/excel-vba-delete-empty-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is as follows

[image]

then try the following code

```
Sub Demo()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7")  'change Sheet7 to your data sheet
        .Range("A1:B23").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
End Sub
```

Change range as per your data. This will give result as

[image]

Comment: Works Perfectly!!