# excel Macro not delete empty rows.Only delete data But I want delete data as well as row

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro.In this it only remove data not rows. For example, if I have 600,000 records and after the macro runs I am left with 15000 records.but In my excel sheet is still showing 600,000 records: 15000 records with data and rest empty. I want it show only 15000 records.All empty row should be deleted. Here is my code:

```
Sub DeleteRecord()
    Dim MySheet As String
    Dim cnt As Long
    MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
        ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"


    cnt = Worksheets(MySheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If cnt > 3 Then Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33
End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you just delete your code? Also, many of those reading the question will not know that 6 lakhs means 600,000.

Comment: Sorry I did not delete code.I recently join.Sub DeleteRecord()
        Dim MySheet As String
        Dim cnt As Long
        MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name
        Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
            ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"
 cnt = Worksheets(MySheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        If cnt > 3 Then Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33
    End Sub

Comment: You accidentally deleted the code when you edited. I can roll it back if you can't figure out how to reverse it.

Comment: If you really have 600,000 records, you might want to use a database rather than Excel.

Comment: no After delete 15000 record left.I have 15000 records

Comment: I have 600000 records in excel.After run macro 15000 records left rest deleted.But in my excel sheet it show 15000 records with data rest are empty.Now I want to delete all empty rows.I only want 15000 records.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9379673/4996248) will help. Note that some of those answers will run slowly in your use-case (the accepted answer is probably the worst of the lot) so look at them all before you decide which one is best.