# Rows are not getting deleted

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is not deleting the rows as expected. Can someone tell me what is wrong with it?

```vb
    With Worksheets("Alerts Ack By Cops")
        For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            Select Case UCase(.Cells(rw, "A").Value2)
                Case "Punna,", "Juleas,"
                    .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
                    i = i - 1
            End Select
        Next rw
    End With
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: **1.** The title of the question is not for asking question. Use the post body for that. Also be clear in what you are asking and indent your code **2.** Proper tagging is required so that it reaches the right audience. :) Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: `"Punna,"` and `"Juleas,"` are only part of their cells' text. You need to use `Left` to extract that part of the text before trying to compare them.

Answer (score 2):

When you are looking for text with capital letter using `UCase` then you need to match with upper case values.

Change

```
Case "Punna,", "Juleas,"
```

to

```
Case "PUNNA,", "JULEAS,"
```

Also since you want to match the cell which starts with those words, you can use `LIKE` as shown below

```
With Worksheets("Alerts Ack By Cops")
    For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If UCase(.Cells(rw, "A").Value2) Like "PUNNA,*" Or _
           UCase(.Cells(rw, "A").Value2) Like "JULEAS,*" Then
                .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next rw
End With
```

Also, using autofilter would be faster. You may want to see [Delete row based on partial text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-partial-text).  Here the cirteria becomes `"=" & strSearch & "*"` instead of `"=*" & strSearch & "*"`

If you still want to delete the rows using a loop then you may want to see `Union` way of doing it in [Excel VBA - Delete empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379673/excel-vba-delete-empty-rows/9379968#9379968) which will increase the speed drastically over a large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Rows Using `AutoFilter`

- The first solution illustrates the use of two criteria.
- The second solution illustrates how to do the same with an array. Unfortunately `AutoFilter` can have only two criteria containing wild characters. If you add more, nothing will be filtered.
- The third solution illustrates a workaround which allows more than two criteria containing wild characters.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteTwoCriteria()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Alerts Ack By Cops")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter _
                Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:="Punna,*", _
                Operator:=xlOr, _
                Criteria2:="Juleas,*"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                On Error Resume Next
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub deleteArray()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Alerts Ack By Cops")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter _
                Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:=Array("Punna,*", "Juleas,*"), _
                Operator:=xlFilterValues
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                On Error Resume Next
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub deleteList()
    Const CriteriaList As String = "Punna,*|Juleas,*|R2*"
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, "|")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Alerts Ack By Cops")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            If .Cells.Count > 1 Then
                Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Value
                Dim dict As Object
                Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
                Dim i As Long
                Dim n As Long
                For i = 2 To UBound(Data, 1)
                    For n = 0 To UBound(Criteria)
                        If LCase(Data(i, 1)) Like LCase(Criteria(n)) Then
                            dict(Data(i, 1)) = Empty
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next n
                Next i
                If dict.Count > 0 Then
                    .AutoFilter _
                        Field:=1, _
                        Criteria1:=dict.Keys, _
                        Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                    End With
                    .Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```